# Applescript move all files from a specific folder name.

Tags: applescript, finder

I have a drive that has multiple "Approved" folders with files in them.

The Approved folders are in various locations on the drive.

I need to move the contents of the Approved folders to another directory via applescript.

This is what I have come up with so far but does not seem to be doing the trick, it runs but no files are moved...

Any tips would be great

Thanks

```
 set sourceFolder to "THIS:" as alias
 set destinationFolder to "THAT:" as alias
   tell application "Finder"
       repeat with aFolder in (get folders of sourceFolder)
          set folderName to name of aFolder
          set filesToMove to (files of sourceFolder whose name = "Approved")
          move filesToMove to destinationFolder
       end repeat
   end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you are looking for **folders** named Approved, but your script is searching for **files** named Approved.  Try this:

```
set sourceFolder to choose folder
set destinationFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
        repeat with aFolder in (get folders of sourceFolder)
            if aFolder's name is "Approved" then
                set filesToMove to (files of aFolder)
                move filesToMove to destinationFolder
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, still does not seem to be moving anything, might try and break it down more.

Comment: In that case, there is still something wrong in how you are setting the folder variables.  I have edited the script to show how I tested it initially.  It works on my machine.